# Can i list possible source types as ones not available?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, memory-leaks, uiimagepickercontroller

I have this code currently:

```
NSArray *mediaTypes = [UIImagePickerController availableMediaTypesForSourceType:imagePicker.sourceType];
imagePicker.mediaTypes = mediaTypes;
```

But it's causing this leak:

```
figremote_createpropertylistfrombinaryplistdata
```

And somebody said to replace it with this:

```
CFStringRef mTypes[2] = { kUTTypeImage, kUTTypeMovie };

CFArrayRef mTypesArray = CFArrayCreate(CFAllocatorGetDefault(), (const void**)mTypes, 2, &kCFTypeArrayCallBacks);

imagePicker.mediaTypes = (NSArray*)mTypesArray;

CFRelease(mTypesArray);
```

The problem is, some devices won't have a movie mode. Would it cause a problem if i allowed that mode and it wasn't available?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there are no devices who do not support video mode exclusively. If a device does not support video mode, it will not support the camera at all. My advice would be to check if the device supports camera at all. In such case, the following code will do.

```
if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera]) {
    NSLog(@"Device supports camera");
} else {
    NSLog(@"Device does not support camera");
}
```